# Exclude package/s in androidTest coverage report

Tags: android, android-testing

Working on Android tests, we want to view the test coverage report. This has been achieved by adding these lines in build.gradle

```
debug {
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

and executing the command:

```
gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

However, we have integrated .aidl files in the project. Now, the methods from .aidl files are being tagged as 'missed instructions' from the coverage report.

As we don't want it to be part of the test, is it possible to exclude a specific package from the when 'createDebugCoverageReport' has been executed? exclude package/s, or files ending in .aidl perhaps?